# Deleting multiple keys at once with jq

Tags: jq

I need to delete multiple keys at once from some JSON (using `jq`), and I'm trying to learn if there is a better way of doing this, than calling map and del every time. Here's my input data:

**test.json**

```
[
  {
    "label": "US : USA : English",
    "Country": "USA",
    "region": "US",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "USD",
    "number": "USD"
  },
  {
    "label": "AU : Australia : English",
    "Country": "Australia",
    "region": "AU",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "AUD",
    "number": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "label": "CA : Canada : English",
    "Country": "Canada",
    "region": "CA",
    "Language": "English",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "CAD",
    "number": "CAD"
  }
]
```

For each item, I want to remove the number, Language, and Country keys. I can do that with this command:

```
$ cat test.json | jq 'map(del(.Country)) | map(del(.number)) | map(del(.Language))'
```

That works fine, and I get the desired output:

```
[
  {
    "label": "US : USA : English",
    "region": "US",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "label": "AU : Australia : English",
    "region": "AU",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  {
    "label": "CA : Canada : English",
    "region": "CA",
    "locale": "en",
    "currency": "CAD"
  }
]
```

However, I'm trying to understand if there is a `jq` way of specifying multiple labels to delete, so I don't have to have multiple `map(del())` directives?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can provide a *stream* of paths to delete:

```
$ cat test.json | jq 'map(del(.Country, .number, .Language))'
```

Also, consider that, instead of blacklisting specific keys, you might prefer to whitelist the ones you do want:

```
$ cat test.json | jq 'map({label, region, locale, currency})'
```

Answer (score 31):

There is no need to use both `map` and `del`.

You can pass multiple paths to `del`, separated by commas.

Here is a solution using "dot-style" path notation:

```sh
jq 'del( .[] .Country, .[] .number, .[] .Language )' test.json
```

- doesn't require quotation marks (which you may feel makes it more readable)
- doesn't group the paths (requires you to retype `.[]` once per path)

Here is an example using "array-style" path notation, which allows you to combine paths with a common prefix like so:

```sh
jq 'del( .[] ["Country", "number", "Language"] )' test.json
```

- Combines subpaths under the "last-common ancestor" (which in this case is the top-level list iterator `.[]`)

peak's answer uses `map` and `delpaths`, though it seems you can also use `delpaths` on its own:

```sh
jq '[.[] | delpaths( [["Country"], ["number"], ["Language"]] )]' test.json
```

- Requires both quotation marks and array of singleton arrays
- Requires you to put it back into a list (with the start and end square brackets)

Overall, here I'd go for the array-style notation for brevity, but it's always good to know multiple ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

A better compromise between "array-style" and "dot-style" notation mentioned in by Louis in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62303827/7314180).

```
del(.[] | .Country, .number, .Language)
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/pL9zZ4YNpT)

---

This form can also be used to delete a list of keys from a nested object (see russholio's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57603738/7314180)):

```
del(.a | .d, .e)
```

Implying that you can also pick a single index to delete keys from:

```
del(.[1] | .Country, .number, .Language)
```

Or multiple:

```
del(.[2,3,4] | .Country,.number,.Language)
```

You can delete a range using the `range()` function (slice notation doesn't work):

```
del(.[range(2;5)] | .Country,.number,.Language)  # same as targetting indices 2,3,4
```

---

Some side notes:

```
map(del(.Country,.number,.Language))
# Is by definition equivalent to
[.[] | del(.Country,.number,.Language)]
```

> If the key contains special characters or starts with a digit, you need to surround it with double quotes like this: `."foo$"`, or else `.["foo$"]`.

Answer (score 14):

This question is very high in the google results, so I'd like to note that some time in the intervening years, `del` has apparently been altered so that you can delete multiple keys with just:

```
del(.key1, .key2, ...)
```

So don't tear your hair out trying to figure out the syntax work-arounds, assuming your version of jq is reasonably current.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, without getting the `jq` error `Cannot index string with string`

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @user3899165's answer, I found that to delete a list of keys from "sub-object"

```
example.json

{
    "a": {
        "b": "hello",
        "c": "world",
        "d": "here's",
        "e": "the"
    },
    "f": {
        "g": "song",
        "h": "that",
        "i": "I'm",
        "j": "singing"
    }
}
```

`$ jq 'del(.a["d", "e"])' example.json`

Comment: Is it possible to delete all ```d | e``` without specifying a and а ? Something like ```jq 'del(.*'["d", "e"])' example.json``` ?

Comment: It's possible ```jq 'del(.[]["d", "e"])' example.json```

Answer (score 6):

`delpaths` is also worth knowing about, and is perhaps a little less mysterious:

```
map( delpaths( [["Country"], ["number"], ["Language"]] ))
```

Since the argument to `delpaths` is simply JSON, this approach is particularly useful for programmatic deletions, e.g. if the key names are available as JSON strings.

Comment: `delpaths` will set to `null` the values of keys found at the path expression(s) provided, it will not remove the key, as requested here.

Comment: @LouisMaddox - I have tested the program given above using jq 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 and in all cases the result is that the keys are deleted.  If you are responsible for the recent downvote, please don't forget to remove it.  Thank you.

Comment: I still find it an undesirable answer: OP stated "I'm trying to learn if there is a better way than calling map and del every time". There is: use a single `del` call, which also reduces the number of square brackets around the path names to 2 rather than your 8: `jq 'del( .[] ["Country", "number", "Language"] )' test.json`. Your answer works, but I find it a potential source of confusion and potentially silent error (since `delpaths` doesn't otherwise delete a key, but sets to `null` while leaving the key present). This has bitten me in the past so I recommend the simpler `del` call instead.

Comment: (a) There is no claim that using delpaths is the best way, just that it is a better way as requested in the Q. (b) Even if a path to a non-existent key is included, the key is not added, so I do not understand your concern about "leaving the key present".

Comment: I'd just been bitten by this yesterday and so downvoted on that basis, it's really as simple as that :-) Didn't mean to offend. StackOverflow won't let me un-downvote unless you edit your answer though. My concern about "leaving the key present" refers to using `delpaths` without `map`, in which case it will set the value at that key to `null` but leave the key itself present.

Comment: (a) The accepted answer uses map(del(...)). (b) I've updated the answer to explain why it might sometimes be useful to know about delpaths.